# How can i find out which hdd is failing

Tags: hard-disk, dmesg

One of my hard driver started to do a noise when i open nemo.
dmesg logs shows

```
[   66.160051] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x2000 SErr 0x30802 action 0xe frozen
[   66.160053] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[   66.160054] ata6: SError: { RecovComm HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt }
[   66.160056] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   66.160059] ata6.00: cmd 60/08:68:f8:29:01/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 40/00:68:f8:29:01/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[   66.160060] ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
[   66.160062] ata6: hard resetting link
[   66.878381] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   67.072157] ata6: hard resetting link
[   70.560148] ata6: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   70.567480] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   70.567491] ata6: EH complete
```

Is there a way to find out the hdd from this dmesg?
I'm on arch linux

Comment: `dmesg` also lists the assigments of `ata6.00` etc. to `/dev/hda` etc. (or use syslog/journalctl). I guess there are also symlinks in `/sys` somewhere. Consider using `smartctl` on the HDD once you've found it.

Answer (score 4):

i found it in my noobish way by first doing `ls /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000\:02\:00.1-ata-6` (using tab to list all links/files and to reach **ata-6**) and then `lsblk /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000\:02\:00.1-ata-6` and got the device mount point/size/name.